# Including Bootstrap Glyphicons In Express

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, glyphicons

I'm trying to use glyphicons (via bootstrap) in my Express app. The problem is when I'm serving my static files, the glyphicons aren't included.

This is my directory (created by grunt):

```
Build

   fonts
       glyphicons-halflings.eot
       ...

   js
       scripts.js

   stylesheets
       styles.css
```

Here is my app.js code:

```
app.use('/build/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build/js')));
app.use('/build/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build/stylesheets')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build/fonts')));
```

Here is the error from chrome:

> users:1 GET
>   http://localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 404 (Not
>   Found) users:1 GET
>   http://localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 404 (Not
>   Found)

I've tried switching to

```
app.use('/build/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build/fonts')));
```

but I'm pretty sure bootstrap is looking for ../fonts, so the dir can't be quite the same. In other words, bootstrap is expecting a structure like so:

```
js/bootstrap.js
fonts/glyphs
```

Where am I off?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the following then:

```
app.use('/fonts/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build/fonts')));
```

Comment: And this is what happens when you spend too much time staring at a screen. *Face-Palm - Thanks @John